# How to rewrite url in Codeigniter with date

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some issues with codeigniter url rewriting.

The problem is that standart htaccess rewriting is not working here.

I want that htaccess rewrite this :

```
http://www.example.com/home/results?date=2017-10-02
```

To

```
http://www.example.com/home/results/2017-10-02
```

Thanks for help!

This not working :

```
RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)$ results?date=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did one of the answer help you? If so, please accept one of the answers: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

its simple you have to create route in route.php file no need make rewrite rule.

```
$route['home/results/(:any)'] = 'home/results';
```

here is CI official doc for url routing

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

you need to add the following rules in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Check here how CI URL work

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

In CI URL are array segments, you can fetch segments with uri class by giving segment number start with 0 after domain name, here you want to get date you segment is 2

```
$this->uri->segment(2);
```

Here link for CI uri class you can find more helpful methods also

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: How to handle date in view? Because $_GET["date"] not working

Comment: If it is passed as proposed in answer you can use `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^date=([0-9]{4}(\-[0-9]{2}){2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/results$ /home/results/%1? [L]
```

The `%1` is to pull the first group from the regex in the `RewriteCond`. The trailing `?` is used so that the query string isn't appended in the rewrite as well.

In Apache the first parameter of the `RewriteRule` directive doesn't include the query string so a `RewriteCond` to check the `%{QUERY_STRING}` must be used.

Also if you want it to be less specific then you can just edit the regex used to match the query string, it currently is very specific in that date must be the only parameter in the query string and that it must be "(4 numbers)-(2 numbers)-(2 numbers)". You can see a breakdown of the regex [here](https://regexper.com/#%5Edate%3D(%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D(%5C-%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)%7B2%7D)%24).